# watir wbdriver browser hangs: Errno::ECONNREFUSED: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I am using FF7.x, when the watir-webdriver sometime causes the browser to hang and throws the following error:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `initialize'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `open'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:67:in `timeout'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in `start'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1035:in `request'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.13.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:81:in `response_for'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.13.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:43:in `request'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.13.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:39:in `call'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.13.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:450:in `raw_execute'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.13.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:428:in `execute'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.13.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:185:in `quit'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.13.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:43:in `quit'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.13.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:162:in `quit'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.3.9/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:85:in `close'
    C:/Perf/AutoItData/scripts/MasterScript.rb:320:in `test_everything_off'
    C:/Perf/AutoItData/scripts/MasterScript.rb:120:in `each'
    C:/Perf/AutoItData/scripts/MasterScript.rb:120:in `test_everything_off'
```

Moreover this issue causes the whole script abortion.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

First, please update all your gems to the latest versions.

Secondly, try a higher Http timeout

```
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.timeout = 180 # seconds – default is 60
b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :http_client => client
```

Comment: Hi Alister, Yes I will update the gems. And the client timeout is already 300 seconds. BTW can you please let me know how to stop the whole script aborting when a single iteration throws exception?

Comment: You should show an example of your script & framework - the way you have set it up would affect how to handle the exception.

Comment: That's a good question, but comments is not a good place for it.  I'd start a new question on that topic Sudhindra